# Jquery function will only fire once

Tags: jquery, function, tabs

The following snippet will only fire the first time I click the `.profile-tabs ul li a` element(s) and not again. If I put the `switchProfTabs()` function directly into the script (instead of calling it) it works as expected. I'm confused why this is. All the answers I've seen to similar questions say it's about event delegation, but I think I'm already using that method, no? Any help appreciated.

```
//Detects whether the form has been changed or not
// Set the boolean flag variable
var form_changed = false;
$('#profile-form').on('input change', 'input, select, textarea', function(){
     form_changed = true;
});

    // Switches the tabs on the profile page
    $('.profile-tabs ul li a').on('click', function() {
        if ($('.tabContent.active').attr('id') == 'profile') {
            if(form_changed){
                var conf = confirm('Profile has not been saved! Press cancel to save before continuing');
                if (conf){
                    switchProfTabs(this);
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                switchProfTabs(this);
            }
        }
        return false;
    });

    function switchProfTabs(clicked) {
        $('.profile-tabs ul li a.active').removeClass('active');
        $(clicked).addClass('active');
        $('.tabContent').hide();
        var tab = $(clicked).attr('data-tab');
        $('.tabContent.active').removeClass('active');
        $('#'+tab).addClass('active').show();
    }
```

Comment: You use one example of delegation at the top for the form controls but not on the tabs. Are the tabs being replaced before event stops working? Any errors showing in console?

Comment: How would I use event delegation on the 2nd one? What action would I hook to? And yes, if I'm understanding your question, the `switchProfTabs()` function works correctly one time (the tab switches as well as the content) but only once. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So delegate to a parent element that is a permanent asset or to document....then use the tabs selector as target the same way you did with the form controls at the top

Comment: Something like `$('#tabs-container').on('click','.profile-tabs ul li a', function(....`

Comment: Like this:? `$(document).on('click', '.profile-tabs ul li a', function switchProfTabs() {
 $('.profile-tabs ul li a.active').removeClass('active');
 $(this).addClass('active');
 $('.tabContent').hide();
 var tab = $(this).attr('data-tab');
 $('.tabContent.active').removeClass('active');
 $('#'+tab).addClass('active').show();
});`

That's still giving me the same behavior. I'm used to PHP where I can just call a function with a variable from anther function, so I'm afraid I'm a bit lost on exactly how this should fit together.

Comment: The delegation is right not at all sure now why it would only work once unless replacement html is slightly different

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. It was a problem with my logic and I needed to add an else statement if the tab was NOT the first one, which is why it was only firing once. Dumb mistake.